# What does a scary debug message from ssh -v really mean?

Tags: ssh

Why does ssh -v say:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This message seems to say that it sends my private key (id_rsa) over the network? But I suspect that I misunderstand what is meant by "Offering" here.

Comment: The message is about public key and it's derived from the private key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trying to authenticate automatically via your SSH public key. By default it uses the public counterpart for the key `/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa`. If you had some other key that you would prefer to use, you could do, for example, `$ ssh-add /home/<user>/.ssh/other_key`.

It's nothing to worry about since only your public key is being sent, which is, by definition, OK to be sent in the open.